# PySerial does not receive data correctly

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I have a little problem receiving data correctly via pySerial: it often does not read the full data or too much of it. Sometimes and sometimes more often, there are additional characters or some characters/parts of the sended data are missing. It seems, PC and the emitter of the data are not synchronised correctly.

In the current example I use a arduino, sending 'Hello World' to the serial port of my PC (os is Ubuntu 14.04), with the following simple code:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Programme initiated\n");
}
```

I use the following python3 code to receive the data:

```
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, timeout=2)
print(arduino.isOpen)
print(arduino)
time.sleep(1)    

while True:
    print(arduino.readline())
```

This is pretty much a simple tutorial example, and here is what I receive (apart from the correct stuff):

```
b'PrProgramme initiated\n'
```

or

```
b'PProgramme initiated\n'
```

or

```
b'ProgProgramme initiated\n'
```

or

```
b'ogramme initiated\n'
```

I moved on with more complex problems in my code, but still I didn't solved that problem. When sending a message in a loop from the arduino (the standard hello world code), it often needs time to stabilise (while that, it again does only show the middle fragment of the data) and after that running quite stable, but even then it sometimes breaks down single lines.

I faced the same difficulties when communicating with a multimeter device. There, it often does not read the first characters or mixes up with previous data.

Did anyone faced that problem before? I think it is a question of synchronisation, but I don't know how to solve it. And what puzzles me, is that I really only used tutorial stuff and it doesn't seem to work properly. Or is it a configuration problem of my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is happening because some different things are going on.

First of all every time you open the serial port, you are causing what is called and "autoreset" and the Arduino reboot. That can be avoided in hardware or even in software by explicitly disabling RST signal on open. How to do that may vary and is out of scope of the question.

Then we have to understand that serial does NOT wait for the other part to be listening to send data; so if you disable the autoreset and connecting to the Arduino you should see random part of output of the program, depending of its current state.

Finally we have some buffer capability on pc (and sometimes even on the UART to USB side), so its not true that if you are not listening that data get lost, it may be still in the buffer.

We could say the first 3 artifact may be given by buffered data + reboot (this happen a lot when you send a lot of data, and that break the autoupload of code and you have to do a manual procedure), while the last one may be something that prevented the buffer to fill, maybe it was disabled by you, maybe some weird timing opening the serial, maybe you disabled the autoreset, maybe time that the arduino got enumerated part of the message was gone.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there, in general, a way to clear the buffer before the communication starts (so to say to solve point 3)?

Comment: try with 
arduino.flushInput()
just after the open